# Sharepoint Online - How do I retrieve document's social tagging information

Tags: client-object-model

Is there any way I can retrieve documents' social tags and notes using Client Object Model? I'm on the client side so I don't have access to Server Objects. I've been searching all around but found nothing on this. Thanks!

Comment: Try using the SocialDataService.asmx web service.